# How to place items inside div in different rows

Tags: html, gwt

I have this small div with two items inside the div

```
<div>
<g:Anchor styleName="anchorStyle nextLine">Administration</g:Anchor>
<g:ListBox styleName="nextLine">
</g:ListBox>
</div>
```

These two items are now appearing in one row. I want to display these two items ,i.e Anchor and listBox in different rows, which are in 1 div

Thanks

Comment: What are anchorStyle and nextLine? You need to post your CSS.  You are also using GWT.  What does the rest of the page look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also add a `<br/>` page break between the elements if you want it done in HTML only.

```
<div>
   <g:Anchor styleName="anchorStyle nextLine">Administration</g:Anchor>
   <br/>
   <g:ListBox styleName="nextLine">Something else</g:ListBox>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GtyC2/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `g:Anchor` or `g:ListBox` are exactly, but you could simply add `display: block;` CSS declaration to `.nextLine` class to display each element as a block-level element which causes elements to be placed in separate lines:

```
.nextLine {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks , but i dont know why your solution is not working for me , the two items are still in one row..

Comment: @junaidp Could you tell me what kind of element are these? there's no `styleName` attribute in HTML, but `class`.

Comment: Anchor is a link in GWT..
but u right , if i use something else other than this anchor it works..dont know what wrong with anchor

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using UIBinder. If it is so this code works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
    <ui:style> 
    .nextLine {
        display: block; 
    }
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <div> 
            <g:Anchor styleName="anchorStyle {style.nextLine}">Administration</g:Anchor>
            <g:ListBox styleName="{style.nextLine}"></g:ListBox>
        </div>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Mind the declaration of style, which is included in the same xml file is done : styleName="{style.nextLine}".